# How to resolve "Manifest merger failed:" in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

When I add implementation "net.gotev:3.5.2" in greadle and build project it says

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-41:19 to override.
```

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.attendance.ams.ams"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "net.gotev:uploadservice:3.5.2"

}
```

````
Here is my AndroidManifest file

```xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.attendance.ams.ams">
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_trim"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_trim"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name=".Initializer"
        >
        <activity android:name=".selectPicActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".attendance" />
        <activity android:name=".makeAttendance" />

    </application>

</manifest>
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android design support library for API 28 (P) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782435/android-design-support-library-for-api-28-p-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` from manifest file

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Setup), adding below lines in `android` section will resolve your issue

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    }
}
```